# How to detect Tor usage with Wireshark?

Tags: virtual-machine

I use Tor inside a Virtual Machine. I run Wireshark on my Host. I want to detect Tor usage (for learning/studying) with Wireshark but don't know how? I have tried [this](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/13590/tor-detection):

```
tshark -r tor_traffic.cap -T fields -R "ssl.handshake.certificate" -e x509af.utcTime -e x509s at.printableString
```

but tshark output doesn't show any cert names. Are there any ways to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1):

You could check the list of Guard nodes from onionoo, for example at this Web site: https://onionoo.torproject.org
You may also filter the traffic to the addresses of your interest for better visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tshark` as mentioned in the question should work fine. However, it will require two pass analysis (which was not used in the provided link), and the filters will need to be updated a bit for more modern wireshark versions.

eg.

```
$ tshark -2 -r tor_traffic.pcap -T fields -R "ssl.handshake.certificate" -e x509af.utcTime -e x509sat.printableString                                                
15-01-23 00:00:00 (UTC),15-09-16 23:59:59 (UTC) www.mo7pofg5qx4qezly.com,www.imhw73oq35uluhcjz.net
15-02-12 00:00:00 (UTC),15-04-21 23:59:59 (UTC)
14-12-01 00:00:00 (UTC),15-05-03 00:00:00 (UTC) www.pghq2hykgwzwkgzghrn.com,www.b62klkcmc7zmt3s.net
...
```

Where `tor_traffic.pcap` has been pre-captured with your favorite tool (Wireshark, tcpdump, etc.). You'll also want to make sure the packet capture is run on whatever interface the VM is using.